# Regex in javascript to replace decimal to a secret text code

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to write a simple function that converts currency values to a code.

I've **managed to do the conversion part** with .replace(). **See jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/j9cdrq73/3/

What I want to do is, replace the 2nd repeating character(s) with letter 'Z'

### Edit

After the dot (. decimal point) it should reset. 50000 DIZZZ.IZ
NOTE the last IZ*  see following examples

```
        number   => after convert =>final (what it should give)
       ---------    -------------  ----------------------------
 So      50000    =>  DI,III.II  =>  DI,ZZZ.IZ
       2677.99    =>   B,EFF.HH  =>   B,EFZ.HZ
     366666.22    => CEE,EEE.BB  => CEZ,ZZZ.BZ
```

Current code

```
    function number_to_code(s) {

    // converting the value to something like 50000.00 to look like currency
    // next replace it with the codes as bellow.

      s = parseFloat(s).toFixed(2).replace(/\d/g, m => ({
        '0': 'I',
        '1': 'A',
        '2': 'B',
        '3': 'C',
        '5': 'D',
        '6': 'E',
        '7': 'F',
        '8': 'G',
        '9': 'H'
      })[m]); 
    
    
    // grouping it with , 
      s = s.replace(/\B(?=(\w{3})+(?!\w))/g, ",");       
     return s;
    }
```

***Better if we can do it all in a single regex to improve efficiency.***

Comment: Shouldn't `50000` be `DI,ZZZ.IZ` ?

Comment: @HaoWu Either that or the last one be `CEZ,EZZ.BZ`.

Comment: 50000 be DI,ZZZ.IZ     ANY  repeating letter with Z  but after the dot it rests again so agin shows the I

Comment: @Hirantha Your sample output says `DI,IZZ.IZ` so it confuses people.

Comment: But if `50000` has to become `DI,ZZZ.IZ` then this `What I want to do is, replace the 2nd repeating character(s) with letter Z` does not apply right?

Comment: `50000.00` -> `DIIII.II` -> `DIZZZ.IZ` -> `DI,ZZZ.IZ`. What did I miss here?

Comment: @HaoWu  Sorry my bad. I've fixed the confutation. Seems like both your answers work now. thank you.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes. I just fixed the confusion. your solution too works fine now. thank you.

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042544/convert-a-javascript-regexp-function-to-a-php I want the same function in php too. thank you.

Comment: @HaoWu could you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042544/convert-a-javascript-regexp-function-to-a-php I want the same function in php too. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups, with a backreference repeating the char 1 or more times that was captured in group 1.

```
([A-Z])(\1+)
```

- `([A-Z])` Capture **group 1**, match a char A-Z
- `(\1+)` Capture **group 2**, repeat 1+ the same char that is captured in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/czQFnc/1)

In the code, you can add another replacement returning the concatenation of group 1 followed by replacing all the characters with `Z` from group 2.

```js
function number_to_code(s) {

  // converting the value to something like 50000.00 to look like currency
  // next replace it with the codes as bellow.

  s = parseFloat(s).toFixed(2).replace(/\d/g, m => ({
    '0': 'I',
    '1': 'A',
    '2': 'B',
    '3': 'C',
    '5': 'D',
    '6': 'E',
    '7': 'F',
    '8': 'G',
    '9': 'H'
  })[m]);

  // grouping it with , 
  s = s
    .replace(/([A-Z])(\1+)/g, (_, g1, g2) => {
      return g1 + g2.replace(/./g, "Z")
    })
    .replace(/\B(?=(\w{3})+(?!\w))/g, ",")

  return s;
}

console.log(number_to_code("50000"));
console.log(number_to_code("2677.99"));
console.log(number_to_code("366666.22"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. but I want to keep first letter same and other repeating letters to be replaced.  do the same after the (.) (decimal point).  DIIIIIIII    will look like DIZZZZZZ.IZ

Comment: @Hirantha You can do the replacement of the repeating characters first in that case. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d)(\1*)
```

Maybe this is what you want.

The first group is any digit, the second groups is the repeated digits(if any). Then you replace them separately.

After that group the entire result with `,`.

```js
function number_to_code(s) {
  return parseFloat(s).toFixed(2)
    .replace(/(\d)(\1*)/g, (_, digit, repeats) => ({
      '0': 'I',
      '1': 'A',
      '2': 'B',
      '3': 'C',
      '5': 'D',
      '6': 'E',
      '7': 'F',
      '8': 'G',
      '9': 'H'
    })[digit] + ''.padStart(repeats.length, 'Z'))
    .replace(/\B(?=(\w{3})+(?!\w))/g, ",");
}

const numbers = [
  '50000',
  '2677.99',
  '366666.22',
];

const result = numbers.map(number_to_code);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow  that works.. let me play with it little more and digest the coding. :)